# Incorporating JS in shiny with Jquery and without Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, shiny

I am trying to incorporate JS into Shiny that is without writing anything to server. Here is the code. Below are 2 methods (one with JQuery and another without JQuery). But without JQuery is not working. Can anyone help me here?

Not working

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(HTML('<p id="res">Value</p>'),
  tags$script("document.getElementById('res').innerHTMl=x")),
  textInput("x", label = "Text")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Working

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    HTML('<p id="res">Value</p>'),
    textInput("x", label = "Text"),
    tags$script("$('#x').on('input', function(){$('#res').text($(this).val());});")
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with straight javascript.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  HTML('<p id="res">Value</p>'),
  textInput("x", label = "Text"),
  tags$script("
               let inputEl = document.getElementById('x');
               inputEl.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
                 document.getElementById('res').textContent = inputEl.value;
                });
              ")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```